# Python NetworkX max_flow_min_cost function running forever

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, networkx

I'm trying to use the max_flow_min_cost on certain graphs, but it seems like sometimes the algorithm runs forever (or at least for an extremely long time), and I don't understand why this is the case. Here is a graph that cause it to run that long. They all have the same nodes

```
nodes = [
    ('1in', {'y': -1, 'x': -1, 'type': 'passenger in', 'number': 1}), 
    ('2out', {'y': 1, 'x': -1, 'type': 'passenger out', 'number': 2}),
    ('destination', {'y': 0, 'x': 0, 'type': 'destination'}), 
    ('2in', {'y': 1, 'x': -1, 'type': 'passenger in', 'number': 2}),
    ('source', {'type': 'meta'}), 
    ('4in', {'y': -1, 'x': 1, 'type': 'passenger in', 'number': 4}),
    ('1out', {'y': -1, 'x': -1, 'type': 'passenger out', 'number': 1}),
    ('4out', {'y': -1, 'x': 1, 'type': 'passenger out', 'number': 4}),
    ('sink', {'type': 'meta'}), 
    ('3in', {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'type': 'passenger in', 'number': 3}),
    ('3out', {'y': 1, 'x': 1, 'type': 'passenger out', 'number': 3})
]

edges = [
    ('1in', '1out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2out', '4in', {'cost': -9.48, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2out', 'destination', {'cost': -10.9, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2out', '3in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('destination', 'sink', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2in', '2out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '2in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '4in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '1in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '3in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('4in', '4out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', '2in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', '4in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', 'destination', {'cost':-10.9, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', '3in', {'cost': -9.48, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('4out', 'destination', {'cost': -10.9, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('3in', '3out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('3out', '4in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('3out', 'destination', {'cost': -10.9, 'capacity': 1})
]
```

If I modify the above graph but make the capacity from destination to sink 2 or 3, it also runs forever. If I make capacity equal to 4, the algorithm runs fine. This is the exact call:

```
nx.max_flow_min_cost(G,'source','sink',weight='cost')
```

Thank you! Any help will be appreciated. It's worth mentioning that G is a Directed Graph (DiGraph)

Edit: I [opened an issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2076) on the NetworkX project, in case it's an issue with their code.

Comment: For the future tabulate the code with 4 spaces in order to make it look like code :P.

Comment: @imaluengo Thank you! In the editor it showed as one line, so I got scared and didn't do it.

Comment: Yep it was just 1 line, I broke it into several lines (one per node and edge) and tabulate it with 4 spaces. The 1 line was scary!

Comment: It looks like you want us to find an endless loop in code that you did not provide!  I would suggest adding debugging print statements until you find where the loop is, then start printing enough context that you can trace through the reasoning that leads to it being an endless loop.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using NetworkX library code, I can't put print statements in their code @btilly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm in `networkx.max_flow_min_cost` is not guaranteed to work if the weights are floating point numbers.  See the original authors question answered at the networkx web site here

https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/2076#issuecomment-210200259

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me:

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edges_from([
    ('1in', '1out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2out', '4in', {'cost': -9.48, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2out', 'destination', {'cost': -10.9, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2out', '3in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('destination', 'sink', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('2in', '2out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '2in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '4in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '1in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('source', '3in', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('4in', '4out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', '2in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', '4in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', 'destination', {'cost':-10.9, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('1out', '3in', {'cost': -9.48, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('4out', 'destination', {'cost': -10.9, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('3in', '3out', {'cost': 0, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('3out', '4in', {'cost': -10.31, 'capacity': 1}), 
    ('3out', 'destination', {'cost': -10.9, 'capacity': 1})
])

>>> nx.max_flow_min_cost(G, 'source', 'sink', weight='cost')
{'1in': {'1out': 0, 'source': 0},
 '1out': {'1in': 0, '2in': 1, '3in': 1, '4in': 1, 'destination': 1},
 '2in': {'1out': 1, '2out': 1, 'source': 0},
 '2out': {'2in': 0, '3in': 1, '4in': 1, 'destination': 1},
 '3in': {'1out': 1, '2out': 1, '3out': 0, 'source': 0},
 '3out': {'3in': 0, '4in': 1, 'destination': 1},
 '4in': {'1out': 1, '2out': 1, '3out': 1, '4out': 0, 'source': 0},
 '4out': {'4in': 0, 'destination': 1},
 'destination': {'1out': 1, '2out': 0, '3out': 1, '4out': 1, 'sink': 1},
 'sink': {'destination': 0},
 'source': {'1in': 0, '2in': 1, '3in': 0, '4in': 0}}
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention that G is a DiGraph

Comment: @Arya edited! Without the `capacity` of the edges directed to the source and sink it works perfectly. The example of the documentation of networkx doesn't have those attributes neither.

Comment: Is there a reason for this? According to the algorithm I'm trying to implement, I have to make a graph with a different capacity from destination to sink, and then return the one with the lowest cost. For example this directed graph works perfectly for every capacity between 1 and 7 for destination to sink: http://pastebin.com/J1tk5xCD

Comment: Basically the problem is that I only want 1 unit going from the source to each of the "in" nodes, and I only want that destination->sink capacity units going through the graph at all.

Comment: Uhmm, seems my mistake. Capacity is actually quite important.. (thought `capacity` was `cost`). More information [available here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.network_simplex.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.network_simplex) (max flow calls that function). My second edit is wrong then (removed), and is still confusing (and hard to debug) why that specific network doesn't converge.

Comment: Yeah, I tried looking at the source code but it was pretty impossible to reason about - there's nothing online that says that certain graphs should never converge though.